# Sql Exception Illegal operation on empty result set while it's working on My Sql Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I wanted to make SQL operations easier with this class, but I am getting an exception indicating the result set is empty. The same query is working in MySQL workbench. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DataBase
{
    private String user = "jsmith";
    private String pass = "LetMeIn";
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java";
    private String Schema, Table;
    private Connection con;
    private ResultSet Result;
    private PreparedStatement pQuery;

    public DataBase(String Database, String Table)
    {
        this.Schema = Database;
        this.Table = Table;
    }

    private boolean createConnection()
    {
        boolean b = false;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            b = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Exception " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            b = false;
        }
        return b;
    }

    public String getStringData(String Desireddata, String fromColumn, String condition)
    {
        boolean b = createConnection();
        String retrivedString = "";
        if (b != false && Schema != null && Table != null) {
            try {
                pQuery = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ? FROM " + Schema + "." + Table + " WHERE ? = ?");
                pQuery.setString(1, Desireddata);
                pQuery.setString(2, fromColumn);
                pQuery.setString(3, condition);
                Result = pQuery.executeQuery();
                Result.next();
                retrivedString = Result.getString(Desireddata);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                retrivedString = "False";
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("No Connection or Database not Defined ");
            retrivedString = "False";
        }
        return retrivedString;
    }
}
```

And the exception:

```
Illegal operation on empty result set.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1056)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:817)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5514)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5434)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5474)
    at sync.DataBase.getStringData(DataBase.java:44)
    ...
```

Comment: You can't use parameter binding for object names (tables, columns, etc.), only for values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You can't use parameter binding on object names, so doing `SELECT ? FROM...` is invalid.
2. You aren't checking the return value from [`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()). If it returns `true` there is data to be read, if it returns `false` there is no more data.

To fix the first problem, you would need to change your code from:

```
pQuery = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ? FROM ... WHERE ? = ?");
```

to:

```
pQuery = con.prepareStatement("SELECT " + Desireddata + " FROM ... WHERE " + fromColumn + " = ?");
```

But make sure that `Desireddata` and `fromColumn` are not derived directly from user input or you will be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

To fix the second problem, change:

```
Result.next();
retrivedString = Result.getString(Desireddata);
```

to:

```
while (Result.next()) { /* You COULD use 'if' instead */
    retrivedString = Result.getString(Desireddata);
}
```

And although not a problem, stylistically you should not have instance variables that start with a capital letter. So instead of `Result` you should use `result` or `resultSet` or `rs`. Typically you would only use a capital letter as the first character if you were defining a new type (like a `class` or `interface`).

Answer (score 0):

Your resultset Result is empty. So before processing, check whether Result is null or not.